# single and double quotes are displaying as HTML - eg &#8217; and &#8220;

Tags: custom-post-types

In titles of custom posts the single and double quotes are displaying as HTML - eg: the string starting with & and ending with ; - in the front end, although in the backend they are just typed as regular straight ' and ".

Not sure what is causing this. Is there any way to fix it?

Sorry if I have used the wrong terminology - not familiar with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove wpuntexturize filter by putting this code in your functions.php - `remove_filter( 'the_title' , 'wptexturize'  );`

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! Thanks Anton.

Comment: Glad it helped you. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem related to `wptexturize()` function.

> **Description**
> Returns given text with transformations of quotes into smart quotes,
> apostrophes, dashes, ellipses, the trademark symbol, and the
> multiplication symbol.

Solution:

```
remove_filter( 'the_title' , 'wptexturize'  );
```